# Optimizing a complex mysql to reduce query time

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a very complex query, I'm already optimized a lot, But I couldn't find a better way to write a more optimized query and reduce the query timings. Let me share details so you can understand it better.

Below is my query.

```
SELECT a.msisdn, GROUP_CONCAT( COALESCE(a.answer, 'skip') order by a.question_id separator ',') as answer,

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( COALESCE(answer, 'skip') order by question_id separator ',') as answer FROM  `campaign_survey_responses`
 WHERE campaign_id = 11559 and question_id=14751 and msisdn=a.msisdn) as a1,
 
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( COALESCE(s.answer, 'skip') order by s.question_id separator ',') as answer 
FROM  `campaign_survey_responses` s left join campaign_survey_questions q on q.id = s.question_id 
WHERE s.campaign_id = 11559 and q.parent_id=5128 and q.sort_order = 0 and s.msisdn=a.msisdn) as sur1,
 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( COALESCE(answer, 'skip') order by question_id separator ',') as answer FROM  `campaign_survey_responses`
WHERE campaign_id = 11559 and question_id=14768 and msisdn=a.msisdn) as a2,

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( COALESCE(s.answer, 'skip') order by s.question_id separator ',') as answer 
FROM  `campaign_survey_responses` s left join campaign_survey_questions q on q.id = s.question_id 
WHERE s.campaign_id = 11559 and q.parent_id=5108 and q.sort_order = 0 and s.msisdn=a.msisdn) as sur2,

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( COALESCE(answer, 'skip') order by question_id separator ',') as answer FROM  `campaign_survey_responses`
WHERE campaign_id = 11559 and question_id=14785 and msisdn=a.msisdn) as a3,

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( COALESCE(s.answer, 'skip') order by s.question_id separator ',') as answer 
FROM  `campaign_survey_responses` s left join campaign_survey_questions q on q.id = s.question_id 
WHERE s.campaign_id = 11559 and q.parent_id=5148 and q.sort_order = 0 and s.msisdn=a.msisdn) as sur3

FROM  `campaign_survey_responses` a
WHERE a.campaign_id = 11559 and a.question_id=14750 group by msisdn limit 500;
```

Above query combines 1 millions rows to make around 50,000 rows only, Now only purpose is to export as csv. But the above query takes too much time when it runs.

I have applied limit of 500 from that query, 500 rows limit is taking around 78.844856977463 seconds, but what about 50K rows? It's going to take down the server.

Any better approach to optimize the query, I'm using Mysql 5.7, Thanks

It returns data like below, for limit 500, there will be 500 record, below are just 2 record as an example.

```
0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'msisdn' => string '3003932957' (length=10)
      'answer' => string '1' (length=1)
      'answer1' => string '4' (length=1)
      'survey1' => null
      'answer2' => null
      'survey2' => null
      'answer3' => null
      'survey3' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'msisdn' => string '3013555354' (length=10)
      'answer' => string '1' (length=1)
      'answer1' => string '3' (length=1)
      'survey1' => string '2,1,1' (length=5)
      'answer2' => null
      'survey2' => null
      'answer3' => null
      'survey3' => null
  2 =>
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `campaign_survey_responses` (
 `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `campaign_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 `question_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 `answer` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `msisdn` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 `campaign_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `campaign_id` (`campaign_id`),
 KEY `question_id` (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9016122 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table structure is added, Basically the system generated calls, based on user input, it gets responses like 1,2,3 etc are added to above table. For example, Its a type of multi level survey. There is one parent question, It has 3 choices, If user choose choice 2, the system will play question related to choice 2. After that question, if user choose any choice, there will be series of 10 questions against choice 2.

Similarly for choice 1, and 3.

```
Parent Question ( it has 3 sub questions )
Each 3 of subquestions has 10 questions each.
```

If user choose sub question 1, system will play 10 questions related to sub question 1, He will not be played other related questions for choice 2,3. It depends on user, which question, he wants to play.

Comment: Please add table definitions to question and `EXPLAIN` results of the original query.

Comment: I know it's fun to try to get everything into a single query, but sometimes an alternate solution is to get the relevant data with smaller/cheaper querie(s), and post-process it with another language.  Not always ideal, but can sometimes be beneficial depending on your setup.

Comment: Table structure is added and bit more explanation added. I have already shared the response which im getting, which is correct for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These composite indexes on `campaign_survey_responses` will help a bunch:

```
INDEX(campaign_id, question_id,  msisdn, answer)
INDEX(campaign_id, msisdn, question_id,  answer)
```

(The first will probably help `a`; the second will probably help `s`.)

Comment: This really helped, just adding composite indexes reduce the query time, It was taking 78 seconds for 500 rows, but after adding indexing, it was taking 0.12 second for 500 rows. 53K rows in less than 3-4 seconds.

Comment: Good.  A new believer in INDEXes.

Comment: Thanks alot, I was using MySQL 5.1 on production server, it is an old project. Indexes really helped.

Comment: The Question says "5.7"; which is it?  The longer you wait to upgrade from 5.1, the harder it will be.  Fortunately, _most_ indexing advice works the same in both versions.

Comment: I have told my client many times to let me upgrade, he doesn't listen. As the project is bigger, Many new changes are coming everyday. I'm using Maria db 10 or Mysql 8 in all new projects.

Comment: Good.  (I assume you mean 10.5 or 10.6; 10.0 is getting quite old.)

Comment: Yeah 10.5.4 and Mysql 8.0.21

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan - 10.5.4 is pre-GA; recommend you upgrade at least to 10.5.12.  The latest 10.6 may be better -- MariaDB has switched to "LTS"; 10.6 will have long-term support.  (10.10, the next LTS, is not GA yet.)

Answer (score 0):

The correlated subquery in the `SELECT` can be a real drag. And you have many of these. If this is unavoidable, I would apply it to subset of results and not entire result. i.e. I would create inline view first

```sql
SELECT 
   -- your correlated subqueries as fields here
FROM
   ( -- start inline view
       SELECT -- your columns
       FROM  `campaign_survey_responses` a
       WHERE a.campaign_id = 11559 and a.question_id=14750 
       GROUP BY msisdn 
       LIMIT 500;
   ) T1
```

This way only 500 records will be involved in correlated subqueries

Comment: All sub queries are same in select fields but they have different where conditions, how will that be possible using your above query?

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan in your `where` in subqueries, you will need to refer to `T1.field`. The Idea here is - you get the base resultset first. Then correlate subqueries to that.... Lets say your main query returns 1000 rows. If those subqueries execute against them all - you get maximum execution times. If you put `LIMIT 500`, you still execute against 1000 but then only take 500. But if you first execute getting 500 without subquery by creating inline view, then  your subqueries will execute against 500 hence cutting half of necessary execution time.

Comment: What you are calling an "inline view", MySQL seems to call a "derived table".

Comment: @RickJames true. But it is a synonymous. It is like "car" and "automobile"